# Creating Stored Procedures with SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

I am writing a python script to create the postgres database using SQLAlchemy. I also want to create Stored Procedures by same way. I checked the SQL Alchemy Documentations but was not able to find whether I can create stored procedure using it or not. Is it Possible to do so? any Tutorials/Examples would help. i found some examples of how to call SP using SQLAlchemy but not about how to create.

Thanks in advance. 
Tara Singh

Comment: Most ORM tools provide mechanisms to use stored procs, but not create them, as the language for creating stored procs tends to be very tightly tied to the database in question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create `stored procedures` (actually, execute any valid `SQL statement`) by using [sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) construct:

```
t = text("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:user_id")
result = connection.execute(t, user_id=12)
```

But this will be more of an *appendix* to the SQLAlchemy rather than designed usage.
Also this cannot be done in a DMBS-independent way, which is one of the benefits using `ORM` tools like SQLAlchemy.
If your aim is to version-control your database schema, you still can use it, but you need to take complete control this process and handle things like dependencies between `stored procedures`, `UDFs`, `views` and create/drop them in the proper order.